# Am I considered E-Commerce when registering for DBA/Affiliate programs?

Tags: legal

I am building multiple websites that are geared toward providing information as well as user submitted content (like fan art). A few ad programs and affiliate programs I have looked at ask me to "Provide a brief description of the kind of business you provide." This question also came up when I went to apply for a DBA. At first I was just going to list my self as an E-commerce site but I am not directly selling anything. Am I still considers an E-commerce site or is there some other designation for what I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your sites are not geared towards selling *anything* (whether printed fanart, T-shirts, etc.), then e-commerce would not be a correct designation.

From your description of what your sites entail, you may look to be designated as a Content site or a Showcase site (depending on whether or not emphasis is given more towards the information or towards the user-submitted content).

References:

- [Network Solutions](http://www.networksolutions.com/education/what-is-ecommerce/): Definition of an ecommerce site
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website#Types_of_websites): Types of sites

Comment: Thanks, I knew E-Commerce was really not right for me but I had not heard of Content Site/Showcase site as designations.